# Automate SQL Server install and restore DB

Tags: sql-server-2014, restore, installation

I’ve been tasked to automate our sql server express installation and with that, create a database from a .bak file.  I found a way to automate the install using a Configuration.ini file which works great.  The part I’m having trouble with is restoring a database as part of (or after) the process.

Does anyone know if this is even possible?  I know 3rd party tools like Red Gate can probably do it but they are rather expensive and the company I work for does not have a big budget for development tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A great choice is [dbatools](https://dbatools.io). They have a command (among many, many others) that can help you with this:

[`Restore-DbaDatabase`](https://dbatools.io/functions/restore-dbadatabase/)

An example,

```
Restore-DbaDatabase -SqlServer server1\instance1 -Path \\server2\backups\$
```

It can do a lot more complicated stuff, too! Check out the [documentation](https://dbatools.io/functions/restore-dbadatabase/) for more info.